# Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

recently i tried to learn android programming with Xamarin in Visual studio 2017
i wrote a simple app that makes call but when i tap Call Button its give this execption error a couple of days ago its worked fine but now i got this error
i did make permission for CALL_PHONE in manifest file
forgive me for my bad english
if anyone knows how to fix this issue let me know ill be greatfull
here is my Code .cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;


namespace Dialer.app
{
    [Activity(Label = "Dialer.app", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button btnCall;
        ListView txtViewNumbers;
        EditText txtUnumber;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            btnCall = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            txtViewNumbers = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            txtUnumber = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            string phone = txtUnumber.Text;
            btnCall.Click += delegate
            {
                var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                callDialog.SetMessage("Dial This Number? " + phone);


                callDialog.SetPositiveButton("ok", delegate
                {
                    var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
                    callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(phone));
                    StartActivity(callIntent); //i get error in this line
                });


                callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Cancel", delegate { });
                callDialog.Show();
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL .....

You are missing the `tel:` prefix on the phone number:

```
var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + phone));
StartActivity(callIntent);
```

**But**, in the latest API levela `CALL_PHONE` is a revoked permission:

> Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx

Instead of being allowed to directly dial a number, you need the user to accept the number via the system dialer, this is done via `ACTION_DIAL`:

```
var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial);
callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + "555-555-1212"));
StartActivity(callIntent);
```